# ubuntu 18.04 second monitor not working

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, gpu

I have a Ubuntu 18.04, install on legion y7000, with NVIDIA 1060m GPU，of course there is a intel integrated GPU card, but I don't use it.  I have three monitors, include two external monitor(through DP-port and HDMI-port respectively) and one internal monitor of LAPTOP.  the one not working is VGA monitor through DP-port. internal monitor is also not working, but i don't care much.
Recently, I upgrade my GPU driver from 430 to 525 Manually. By below commands.

- reboot,
- ctrl+alt+f2 to console, login as root.
- sudo service lightdm stop( I happen to know my display manager was gdm3, not lightdm after this)
- sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*
- sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
- sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.105.17.run
- sudo reboot

before upgrade NVIDIA GPU driver, in Ubuntu setting panel, I close the usage of internal monitor of Y7000, only use two external monitors.

after upgrading, my external monitory through DP-port not working, which is weird. I can see it in NVIDIA x server setting and in Ubuntu system setting panel, use xrandr can also see this screen. but after I switch signal input from others to VGA in monitor manipulator panel, there is only black and no output. I can set join display or mirror display in ubuntu system setting panel, in any way there is no image output in that monitor.
I am currently use gnome\gdm3\xorg\xserver, the software stack is very complicated, that is all I know. I wonder it may not possible be the problem of the new driver version of NVIDIA GPU. support such two monitors would be common.
below is xrandr output

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

below is my Ubuntu system setting panel

[image: Ubuntu system setting panel]

system infomation:
uname -a

```
Linux lenovo 4.15.0-48-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 3 08:28:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Nouveau is banned through
t this
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

below is xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 525.105.17

# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 525.105.17

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "AOC 24P1W1"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "AOC 24P1W1"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1920x1080_60_0 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1920x1080_50 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1920x1080_60i +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1920x1080_50i +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1680x1050 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1440x900 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x1024 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x1024_60 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x960 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x720 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x720_60_0 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x720_50 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1024x768 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1024x768_70 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1024x768_60 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600_72 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600_60 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600_56 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 720x576 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 720x480 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 640x480 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 640x480_72 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 640x480_60 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 640x480_60_0 +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {viewportin=1366x768, viewportout=1920x1079+0+0}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {viewportin=1280x800, viewportout=1728x1080+96+0}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

below is my nvidia x server setting

[image]

And I try those three monitors in windows10 OS, every thing was fine. So the hardware would be no problems.

output of sudo lshw -C display

```
[sudo] alvin 的密码： 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:149 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4000000-a407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:147 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

nvidia-smi

```
Tue Apr 25 16:32:08 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.105.17   Driver Version: 525.105.17   CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   57C    P8     4W /  78W |    263MiB /  6144MiB |      2%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3254      G   ...398893387193384678,131072      102MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5114      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                126MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5350      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               30MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager

```
/usr/sbin/gdm3
```

Comment: Is it worth spending time on 18.04?  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was released in 2018-April (why it's 18.04 given the *year.month* format) with 5 years of *standard* supported life, ie. it's got mere days left?  Why not plan instead on the *release-upgrade* or re-install process; as the more changes you make now - the more difficult the *release-upgrade* **may** become in only a few days.

Comment: Thank you guiverc for your reply, I use this machine heavily, and there is much software to install if I upgrade to 22.04, so I try to keep it this way.